# Как получить координаты по адресу?

Tags: android, google-maps-api, координаты

Как можно получить координаты по адресу?

Answer (score 3):

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context);  
List<Address> addresses;
addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(<Аддресс писать сюда>, 1);
if(addresses.size() > 0) {
    double latitude= addresses.get(0).getLatitude();
    double longitude= addresses.get(0).getLongitude();
}
```

Ответ на вопрос находится в гугле за 12 секунд. 12 секунд, Карл!*(с)*